# Gemfileのplatformオプションについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsチュートリアルの第一章の[Gemfile](https://railstutorial.jp/chapters/beginning?version=5.1#code-gemfile_pg_gem)内の

`gem 'byebug',  '9.0.6', platform: :mri`

の platform: :mri オプション はどのような意味ですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のサイトに`platfrom`で指定できる値が確認できます。

[Gemfile | Bundler日本語ドキュメント | Ruby STUDIO](http://ruby.studio-kingdom.com/bundler/gemfile/)

```
ruby | C Ruby (MRI) or Rubinius, but NOT Windows
mri  | Same as ruby, but not Rubinius
```

Rubyの処理系(実装)にはいくつか種類があって、そのうちのどれを選ぶか、ということのようです。

[RubiniusのArray#productをブロック付きで呼んだら…](https://qiita.com/jkr_2255/items/b3d1fcb3f3a3d6b0df2c)

> **Rubiniusって？**
>   Rubiniusは、Rubyの実装の1種です。特徴としては「スピード志向」ということと、「大半の部分がRubyで書かれている」ということがあります1。標準実装のMRI（CRuby）、Java上での実装のJRubyと並んで、そこそこメジャーなRuby処理系の1つです。